# Could not be located in the dynamic link library OPENGL

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

My OpenGL program runs successfully on other computers.
But on my laptop, it gives the following error:

`The procedure entry point __glutCreateWindowWithExit could not be located in the dynamic link library /^^^/^^^.exe`  **NOT .dll**

This `.exe` file is my program generating `.exe` file.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd start by actually linking the *GLUT* library (GLUT is not part of OpenGL, but a 3rd party library). If you don't have that library, download it (I recommend getting the FreeGLUT variant), build it and install it at a location where your toolchain can find it.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I have the GLUT library. I changed the version of the glut32.dll. It worked